# Virtual ListView with checkbox support for vsIcon and vsSmallIcon?

Tags: listview, delphi, checkbox, vcl

I am using ListView in Delphi. I set the OwnerData property to true so that I will provide data of the item in OnData event.

Moreover, I want to add a checkbox to each item of the list view. But the Checkbox property only supports vsList and vsReport mode, not vsIcon and vsSmallicon. Is there a workaround for it? Or is there any ready-to-use 3rd party VCL that supports such a feature?

Comment: Use virtual tree view

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you mean virtual tree view at https://www.jam-software.com/virtual-treeview/ ? But this is a tree view, not list view.

Comment: Look harder. That control can do what you want.

Comment: @alancc despite its name, `TVirtualTreeView` can also be used in a ListView-like fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But the Checkbox property only supports vsList and vsReport mode ...

That's not correct. You are looking at VCL [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.Checkboxes) which states

> Set [Checkboxes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.Checkboxes) to true to make check boxes appear next to the list
>   items when ViewStyle is vsList or vsReport. ...

This is outdated information. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/extended-list-view-styles#lvs_ex_checkboxes) for the native control:

> [Version 6.00 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/common-control-versions) Check boxes are visible and functional with all
>   list view modes except the tile view mode introduced in ComCtl32.dll
>   version 6. ...

Indeed if you try it on a regular `TListView` control in one of the icon modes, you'll see there are no problems with check boxes.

---

However that's not going to help you. In this regard your question is malformed, it has the assumption that `Checkboxes` work OK in list and report modes with a virtual list view control. That's not the case.

Check boxes are good when you can use the `Checked` property on a list item. In a virtual list view control there are no items you can *check*. I'm quoting from the [`LVM_SETITEMCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lvm-setitemcount) message:

> If the list-view control was created without the [LVS_OWNERDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-view-window-styles) style,
>   sending this message causes the control to allocate its internal data
>   structures for the specified number of items. ...
>
> ...
>
> If the list-view control was created with the [LVS_OWNERDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-view-window-styles) style (a
>   virtual list view), sending this message sets the virtual number of
>   items that the control contains.

All the control knows is that there are that many items, there is no per item storage. VCL reflects the API control: when you request an item and your control has `OwnerData` set, the `OnData` event handler is called on a temporary item to reflect the item's properties.

In a virtual list view you manage checks by using state images. Quoting from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-view-controls-overview#list-view-image-lists):

> ... You can use state images, such as checked and cleared check boxes,
>   to indicate application-defined item states. State images are
>   displayed in icon view, small icon view, list view, and report view.

---

Below you'll find a basic implementation which holds item state information in a separate array. To run it, create a blank new form, create an `OnCreate` handler for the form and paste the code.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,   Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ImgList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FListView: TListView;
    FListViewCheckStateArray: array of 0..1;
    procedure ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
    procedure ListViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
        Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  FListView := TListView.Create(Self);
  FListView.Parent := Self;
  FListView.Align := alClient;
  FListView.OwnerData := True;
  FListView.ViewStyle := vsSmallIcon;

  FListView.StateImages := TImageList.Create(Self);
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Bmp.SetSize(16, 16);
  DrawFrameControl(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, Rect(0, 0, 16, 16), DFC_BUTTON,
      DFCS_BUTTONCHECK);
  FListView.StateImages.Add(Bmp, nil);
  DrawFrameControl(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, Rect(0, 0, 16, 16), DFC_BUTTON,
      DFCS_BUTTONCHECK or DFCS_CHECKED);
  FListView.StateImages.Add(Bmp, nil);
  Bmp.Free;

  FListView.Items.Count := 257;
  SetLength(FListViewCheckStateArray, FListView.Items.Count);

  FListView.OnData := ListViewData;
  FListView.OnMouseDown := ListViewMouseDown;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := Format('This is item %.2d', [Item.Index]);
  Item.StateIndex := FListViewCheckStateArray[Item.Index];
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  if (Button = mbLeft) and
      (htOnStateIcon in FListView.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y)) then begin
    Item := FListView.GetItemAt(X, Y);
    Assert(Assigned(Item));
    FListViewCheckStateArray[Item.Index] :=
        Ord(not Boolean(FListViewCheckStateArray[Item.Index]));
    FListView.UpdateItems(Item.Index, Item.Index);
  end;
end;

end.
```

PS: Drawing artifacts should be the subject of a different question.